# Store data in S3 using Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am totally new to Cloud Computing and AWS. I want to develop a simple project using .Net. I want to develop a simple registration/login pages. I have visual studio 2010 and downloaded and installed SDK for .net from aws.amazon.com. I couldnt find as to how to store data onto S3 or in simple terms how and where am I supposed to put the data from where I can access using the sql queries. Can anyone help me with this and also can anyone give example of this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little bit confusing. S3 is a storage service, designed for storing files. From what I understood from your question, you're trying to store relational data. If so, I recommend you either use Amazon RDS or install a DBMS on an EC2 instance. That's the path to follow. Other than that, storing files in S3 is simple. By following Amazon S3 [documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/s3/) and [FAQs](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/), you should be able to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run .NET applications on EC2, you might want to give [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) a closer look. AppHarbor takes the hassle out of deploying and scaling .NET applications so that you can get started quickly and never have to configure, update or manage a single server.

(disclaimer, I'm co-founder of AppHarbor)